# Comportamento de retorno de data do Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, return

Minha dúvida é técnica.

Gostaria de compreender melhor o que aconteceu.
Passei alguns dias tentando resolver um problema no meu código. Achei que as funções do `ajax` ou do `php` estavam erradas. Duas funções de `PHP` eram muito parecidas, porém, uma funcionava e a outra não. Ambas deveriam retornar uma variável `$resposta`, com um código HTML a ser inserido na página. Ex:

```
$resposta = '<span>Alô mundo!</span>';
```

No fim, reparei que a que funcionava tinha as linhas de código:

```
echo $resposta;
return $resposta;
```

e a que não funcionava tinha apenas

```
return $resposta
```

Acontece que o comando 'echo' era o que realmente estava funcionando.
Então, minha dúvida é: se a função em ajax dizia:

```
function chamaM(id_chamado){ //-------> Estava funcionando
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'scriptPHP3.php',
        data: 'id=' + id_chamado,
        success: function(data){
            $('#teste').html(data);
        }
   });
}

function chamaTb(id_chamado, id_m){ //-------> NÃO estava funcionando
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'scriptPHP3.php',
        data: { id: id_chamado, ind_m: id_m },
        success: function(data){
            $('#teste').html(data);
        }
   });
}
```

Porque 'success' está retornando o 'echo' e não o 'return'? Pergunto porque só coloquei o echo para ver se a função estava funcionando. Caso contrário, estaria tentando entender o erro até agora. Agradeço imensamente pela resposta. Caso precisem, aqui está o código relevante em HTML e PHP:

```
.HTML

    <div id="menu-container">
        <a id="m1" class="ativo">m1</a>
        <a id="m2">m2</a>
        <a id="m3">m3</a>
    </div><!-- #menu-container -->

    <div id="teste">/*DIV ONDE SERÁ POSTO O CONTEÚDO PROCESSADO*/</div>


.PHP

if (isset( $_POST["ind_m"] ) && isset( $_POST["id"] ) ) {
    cliqueTb( $_POST["id"], $_POST["ind_m"] );
} elseif (isset ($_POST["id"] ) ) {
    cliqueM( $_POST["id"] );
 }

function cliqueTb( x, y ) { //-------> NÃO estava funcionando
    PROCESSAMENTO;
    return $resposta;
}

function cliqueM( x ) { //-------> Estava funcionando
    PROCESSAMENTO;
    echo $resposta;     //-------> 'echo' retorna o valor e não o 'return'
    return $resposta;
}
```

Comment: Cara, não sei se ajuda, mas acredito que você tenha que converter os dados pra JSON antes. Dessa maneira:
 data: JSON.stringify({ id: id_chamado, ind_m: id_m }),

Comment: Vlw @EricoSouza vou procurar saber mais sobre JSON

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sua pergunta técnica tem uma resposta muito, mas muito simples mesmo.

AJAX é uma técnica para se requisitar **conteúdo** de um endereço "nos bastidores". Esse conteúdo é o *output* que o servidor enviou ao browser como resposta.

E como que uma aplicação envia conteúdo? Ecoando / "printando" algo no programa. Quando a requisição se completar, aquele conteúdo será mostrado para quem requisitou, seja uma pessoa, seja uma rotina programática.

[return](http://www.php.net/return) **não produz conteúdo**, ele desvia o fluxo de execução do programa do escopo local de uma função para o global/externo:

```
$name = 'Bruno Augusto';

$age = getAge();

function getAge() {
    return 26;
}

echo 'Nome: ', $name, ' .Idade: ', $age; // Nome; bruno Augusto. Idade: 26
```

Enquanto definindo as variáveis, estamos no escopo global/externo. Daí temos uma função PHP que tem um escopo próprio, local, independente. E depois temos o *echo*, de volta ao escopo global, que mostra a frase.

Sem o [return](http://www.php.net/return) a execução do código entraria na função quando a mesma fosse invocada (**$age**), mas nunca sairia dela.

E se [return](http://www.php.net/return) não produz conteúdo, não vai existir um *Response Body*. E se não tem corpo, não tem com o que o AJAX trabalhar.

Comment: no caso, o que seria melhor? 1)colocar um 'echo' fora da função, recebendo o 'return $resposta' da mesma. 2)ou deixar o 'echo' dentro da função, sem usar 'return'. Pelo o que entendi, não é uma boa prática fazer a segunda opção.

Comment: O realmente ideal é você ter, no máximo, dois echos ao longo de TODA a Aplicação. Mas como isso envolve Orientação a Objetos e muita complicação desnecessária para o escopo da pergunta, prefira SEMPRE um `return` dentro de uma função porque dessa forma você consegue controlar o *output* da forma que precisar, seja pelo simples posicionamento do elemento no HTML, seja por interagir com CSS/JS.

Comment: Obrigadão @Bruno e a todos. Me ajudaram bastante! Vou melhorar meu código de acordo com o que vcs me ensinaram.

Answer (score 1):

O seu código JavaScript/jQuery faz uma requisição HTTP ao servidor. O PHP recebe, trata e responde a essa requisição. As duas linguagens (JavaScript e PHP) não conversam diretamente, apenas via requisições e respostas HTTP.

No caso de um HTML, uma resposta HTTP é basicamente texto, contendo o seu HTML. O comando `echo` do PHP escreve na saída do programa, que é o que vai para a resposta HTTP. O `return` não escreve na saída, apenas faz a função retornar um valor para quem a chamou (no próprio PHP). E a chamada que não funcionava estava nesta linha:

```
cliqueTb( $_POST["id"], $_POST["ind_m"] );
```

A linha não faz nada com o retorno da função. Ela poderia escrever o valor retornado na saída do programa, que seria uma outra forma de fazer o conteúdo aparecer na resposta HTTP:

```
echo cliqueTb( $_POST["id"], $_POST["ind_m"] );
```